# Cannot drag jcrop selection with the mouse

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I have this weird issue with jcrop that I have spent hours trying to figure out. The problem is that I cannot drag / move the selection around in the same way as it is shown in the [demo](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=basic).

If I try to initialize the script with `setSelect` so that the image appears with a selection when the page loads, **that** selection is movable, but once I make a selection with the mouse, this selection (that replaces the initial one of course) cannot be dragged no matter what I do. It can, however, be moved with the keyboard, but I cannot rely on people using the keyboard.

I have googled around and the only thing that came close was this post: [Cannot drag selection in Jcrop, what could break it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380969/cannot-drag-selection-in-jcrop-what-could-break-it) but that doesn't solve the problem for me (and I have no relative positioning that I know of so it wouldn't be the cause of the problem in the first place).

I use the following setup using jquery 1.4.2 and jcrop 0.9.8 on a mac (have tried both Firefox and Safari):

```
    function updateCoords(c) {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };

    function checkCoords()  {
        if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
        alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
        return false;
    };

    $('#jcrop_target').Jcrop({
            minSize: [ 620,400 ],
            maxSize: [ 620,400 ],
            onSelect: updateCoords,
            onChange: updateCoords
    });
```

but I have also tried using a simple `$('#jcrop_target').Jcrop();` to make sure that it wasn't the other functions causing a conflict.

Any input will be very, very appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Lars

Comment: Could you provide a live link or a http://jsfiddle.net (or http://jsbin.com :) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Matt, I cannot provide you with a link right now (working on a local server), but perhaps I could try jsbin.com - will have to look into that. Until then, any comments are more than welcome :)

Comment: I was just putting an example together for you on jsbin.com and much to my surprise, I could not reproduce the error here: the selection was perfectly movable like it is the demo. So now I just have to figure out what is causing the conflict in my local setup. It could be anything really. Do you have any suggestions? I really don't know what to look for..

Comment: It turned out that I actually **did** have a position:relative in my css like described in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380969/cannot-drag-selection-in-jcrop-what-could-break-it so removing that solved it :)

Comment: @Lars where exactly did you have that position:relative fixed? I am experiencing the same problem but can not find which elements need to be positioned as absolute

Answer (score 1):

> It turned out that I actually did have a position:relative in my css like described in this post:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3380969/

> so removing that solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem in a project where someone had declared position relative on all divs in the CSS. Unfortunately it would have required too much work to fix it, so I had to dig through the code a bit to find a fix.

With the latest jCrop library (Jcrop-0.9.12 at the time of this posting) there is a minor change to the script that fixed the issue for me.

At around line 1122 in jquery.Jcrop.js looks like this:

```
       if (Touch.support) {
            $track.bind('touchstart.jcrop', Touch.createDragger('move'));
        }

        $img_holder.append($track);
        disableHandles();
```

By changing the $img_holder.append($track) to $hdl_holder.append($track) and ensuring that the $hdl_holder is position absolute, it resolved this issue for me. Something with the relative positioning and zindexing was killing it for me.

The two changes to the script I made are:

**Line 350 jquery.Jcrop.js:**

```
$hdl_holder = $('<div />').width('100%').height('100%').css('zIndex', 320),
```

*Changed to:*

```
$hdl_holder = $('<div />').width('100%').height('100%').css({
    zIndex: 320,
    position: 'absolute'
}),
```

**Line 1122 jquery.Jcrop.js:**

```
$img_holder.append($track);
```

*Changed to:*

```
$hdl_holder.append($track);
```