# JCrop drag function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcrop

I'm using JCrop v0.9.12 and I've just found out that having Position: Relative; for all div's will disable the function.  I don't particularly want to go back and change all of my css scripting at this point in the project so I wanted to know if there was another way around this?

I've tried the one where you change lines 350 & 1122 and that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot drag jcrop selection with the mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148175/cannot-drag-jcrop-selection-with-the-mouse)